No puedo acceder a mi servidor Nginx mediante el link que cree
Bueno hace unos días que estoy tratando de usar nginx para un servidor local de pruebas para mis aplicaciones y de paso aprender como se usa nginx cuestión estoy usando Ubuntu WSL para usar nginx con todo lo que esto conlleva configure en su totalidad nginx tal como lo indica la documentación y millares de tutoriales al respecto pero a la hora de usar el dominio asignado a los sitios del servidor no hay respuesta del mismo.
Pero si uso las "ip's" que posee mi carpeta de /etc/hosts/ ese se accede sin problemas al igual si es que uso "localhost"
Hasta ahi supongamos que todo bien pero a la hora de hacer los certificados ssl y esas cosas me da error por todos lados por que no hay respuesta del dominio.
Espero que me puedan ayudar con esto
A continuación adjunto las configuraciones que hice:
CONFIGURACION PAGINA EN NGINX
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

  
    root /var/www/pruebaej;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name pruebaej.com www.pruebaej.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

CONFIGURACION DE LA IP DEL DOMINIO

RESULTADOS AL INGRESAR A LOS DOMINIOS CITADOS



esta mal, si nginx esta corriendo sobre el mismo OS, la ip es 127.0.0.1 y vos tenes 127.0.1.1 esto es incorrecto

si la tienes en un servidor aparte y la ip es 68.227 tienes que reiniciar el servicio de nginx

otra cosa evita usar el .com, usa algo como .dev

nginx esta corriendo en ubuntu desde windows terminal usando wsl pero si no estoy entendiendo mal tu comentario el problema radicaría en que estoy usando la ip incorrecta para asignar los sitios que eh creado esto seria correcto no?

Entre otras cosas aplique los cambios que has sugerido pero pese a que parecía bien encaminado no hay cambio alguno aunque me di cuenta que una de las paginas no estaba siendo consumida directamente y no importa la ip que use o como la configure solo consume el .html de la 1era pagina que se creo

si y no puede ser que haga falta reiniciar el servicio o usar algo diferente al  .com

en eso era el caso ya cambie los .com de los dominios a .dev y bueno ya eh reiniciado el servicio usando "systemctl restart nginx" en modo root claro esta y sigo en la misma pero parece que es problema de usar wsl en vez de una distro nativa ya que hay que sanear el tema de las conexiones que no reconoce windows como tal a la hora de ejecutar ubuntu en wsl pero seguiré intentando y investigando en tal caso

@Lion tu problema radica en los siguiente: tu navegador se ejecuta en windows, el NO tiene accesos a las configuraciones de /etc/hosts porque esas configuraciones estan en Ubuntu. Deja tu archivo /etc/hosts como lo tenias al inicio y en windows modifica este archivo como administrador C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts (asegurate de guardarlo como 'todos los archivos' para que no genere un .txt aparte) y ponle algo como esto ::1 my.dominio.com luego limpia los dns cacheados con este comando en el cmd: ipconfig /flushdns. Finalmente reinicia el navegador y prueba.

Mirate este issue, que me parece es el problema que estas teniendo y un usuario propone una solucion similar a mi comentario anterior: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5728#issuecomment-917295590 (aunque yo no modificaria el archivo de ubuntu)
